# Getting results quickly from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am working on the hotel booking site for a client using PHP, MySQL on which hotels will have their login and manage their room rates, special offers, minimum stay booking, last minute deals etc...
I am done with that but facing issue with fetching rates fast from database as I have to fetch rates following tables and in following flow.
When user selects dates, I search in table tbl_availability which stores date and no. of available rooms, then in special offer table I store offers available for selected dates to check if user is qualified for any special rate, then I check in minimum stay table to check if hotels has added any minimum stay limitation on dates selected by users and at last I check if the dates have any last minute deal available. I need to search this for all hotels and then show the result to user. This is working but taking very much time (almost 60-90 seconds to return the result) and on top of this if user selects 2 rooms then I need to check this for 2 rooms as offers and minimum stays are manage on room level.

The one thing I think will help is, I will run cron and store everything in one table for next 1 year and update that table on each booking or every time hotel changes anything.

Has anyone worked on similar scenario before and found a way to fetch the results very quickly from database?

Comment: doesn't matter how fast you can fetch if your design is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of query try to use http://memcached.org/ to store cache in memory.

Comment: Hi Mauricio, I tried with memcached but it can be any combination of check in date, checkout date, no of rooms, adults and children. It's only 2 out 100 times the search will be same so I will need to run fresh query most of the time.